# When are reputation points awarded?

Tags: support, reputation

There has been no update in my reputation points for today. Is the system down, as I believe that the system is automated in awarding the points. Anyone experiencing the same problem today?

Comment: Isn't it just that no one is upvoting your questions/answers?

Comment: I did some reviews earlier this mornings, Doesn't that contributes to some points. By the way, @nhahtdh I saw you have been actively editing ac couple of questions and answers, but your reputation for today haven't change tough.

Comment: Edit (when you have the "Edit anywhere" privilege) and review don't give reputation. Suggesting edit (for user without "Edit anywhere privilege") gives +2 reputation if approved.

Comment: @nhahtdh so all your recent edit does not contribute to any reputation. So you have been doing a charity work, Salute ya for doing so.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reviewing doesn't give you any reputation point, but **please continue to do so**, since it keeps the quality of the site in control.

There are 4 levels of unsupervised edit privilege:

1. [Edit your own questions and answers](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-posts)
2. [Edit community wiki](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki)
3. [Edit [any] questions and answers](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit)
4. [Edit tag wiki](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)

If you haven't earned the privilege, you can still suggest edit, which will be peer reviewed. You get +2 reputation for every approved suggested edit.

If you have earned the privilege, no reputation is given. However, please do continue to edit to keep the site quality high. We don't want to attract craps.